# Understanding Terence Tao's proof of Cayley-Bacharach's theorem.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, curves, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

I am studying Cayley-Bacharach's theorem, which Tao states as [(here)](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/pappuss-theorem-and-elliptic-curves/)

> **Theorem (Cayley-Bacharach).** Let $\gamma_0 = \{ P_0(x,y) = 0\}$ and $\gamma_\infty = \{ P_\infty(x,y) =0 \}$ be two cubic curves that
> intersect (over an algebrically closed field $k$) in precisely nine
> distinct points $A_1,\dots,A_9.$ Let $P$ be a cubic polynomial that
> vanishes on eight of those points (say $A_1,\dots,A_8).$ Then $P$ is a
> linear combination of $P_0,P_\infty$ and in particular vanishes on the
> ninth point $A_9.$

After this, Tao presents a proof of this theorem which I believe I understand almost totally, there is just one small detail that I am not getting. Below I will show an outline of the proof presented in the link above (just the topics) and be more detailed in the part that I didn't get.

**Outline of proof.** Essentialy, we can split the proof Tao did in the following steps:

1. Let $P$ be a cubic polynomial that vanishes on the points $A_1,\dots,A_8$ such that $P$ **is not** a linear combination of $P_0,P_\infty.$
2. Some observation on the $9$ original points: no four of these can be colinear and no seven of these can lie on the same quadric.
3. A consequence of the observations above: any five points from $\{A_1,\dots,A_9\}$ determine a unique quadric curve $\sigma$.
4. Some further conclusions: no three points from $\{ A_1,\dots,A_8\}$ are colinear and no six points from $\{A_1,\dots,A_8\}$ lie on the same quadric curve.

After this, Tao continues: Finally, let $l$ be the line that goes through the points $A_1,A_2$ and let $\sigma$ be the quadric curve that goes through $A_3,\dots,A_7.$ Note that the quadric curve must be a conic section based on $4.$ Even more, from $4.$ It also follows that $A_8 \notin l$ and $A_8 \notin \sigma.$ Now let us consider two points $B,C$ that are in $l$ but not in $\sigma.$ We can construct $Q = aP + bP_0 + cP_\infty$ such that $Q$ vanishes in $B$ and $C$. Furthermore, $Q$ vanishes in $4$ points of $l$ $(B,C,A_1,A_2)$ and thus $l$ must be a component of $Q$ (Bézout). The other component must be a quadric curve (degree comparasion). Also, this quadric curve must contain the points $A_3,\dots,A_7$ and thus it must be $\sigma$, based on $3.$ But then $Q$ doesn't vanish at $A_8$, which is a contradiction, because $A_8$ vanishes at the three polynomials $P$, $P_0$ and $P_\infty$.

**My doubt.** I believe I understand almost every argument that Tao used: I just don't see where we use the fact that $P$ **is not** a linear combination of $P_0,P_\infty.$ Basically, I understand that we find a contradiction and how we find it, I just don't see how the fact that $P$ is not a linear combination of $P_0$ and $P_\infty$ influences this same contradiction. As far as my mind can think, we would reach this same contradiction if $P$ was a linear combination of $P_0,P_\infty$. I don't see what I am missing but it must be something really trivial.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $P$ is not a linear combination of $P_0$ and $P_\infty$, $\{P,P_0,P_\infty\}$ is a linearly independent set of degree $3$ polynomials. Let $B$ and $C$ be two points as above. We need to find a nonzero $Q=aP+bP_0+cP_\infty$ such that $Q$ vanishes at both $B$ and $C$. This is the same as solving the system
$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
P(B)& P_0(B)&P_\infty(B)\\
P(C)& P_0(C)&P_\infty(C)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align},$$
where $P(B)$ denotes $P$ evaluated at $B$ etc. A nontrivial solution $(a,b,c)$ exists in this case and hence a nonzero $Q$.

If $P$ were a linear combination of $P_0$ and $P_\infty$, we would only have a $2\times 2$ matrix, and there is no guarantee of a nontrivial solution to the system.

Comment: Thanks for your help @cqfd. My linear algebra is long gone... I understand that finding $Q$ with such conditions is equivalent to solve the system you presented. What is the result you used to guarantee that this system has a nontrivial solution ? On the other hand, what result are you using to say that when the matrix is $2 \times 2$ there is no guarantee of existence of a nontrivial solution?

Comment: Both can be explained using the rank nullity theorem. In the first case, the rank of the matrix is at most 2 (= the dimension of the codomain), the dimension of the domain is 3, so the dimension of the kernel is at least 1, and hence there is a nontrivial solution to the system above. This argument does not work if you have a $2\times 2$ matrix.